# Ruby on Rails deep order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with deep sorting in Ruby on Rails. I have the following associations.

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :station
end

class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :devices
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :station

  validates :street, :suburb, :state, :postcode, :country, presence: true
end
```

And now I want to order all devices by its station adress street field. Is there any way to do this deep merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Given that the `Address` model's table's name is `addresses`, that all `devices` have a `station`, and that all `stations` have one `address`, you could use the following:

```
Device.
joins(station: :address).
order("addresses.street ASC") # you can change ASC to DESC
```

The above `joins` applies inner joins. In case there are 'missing' associations e.g. a `station` doesn't have an `address`, then you will need to use outer joins, either explicitly with raw SQL or using the `includes` method.